# Hilbert space sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let
$$
L^2:=\left\{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R \; \middle| \; \int_0^1 |f|^2 < \infty\right\},
$$
$$
\langle f,g \rangle:= \int_0^1 f g,
$$
and
$$
\|f\| := \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}.
$$

Prove that $\|f_n-f\| \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ exactly when the limit of $\langle f_n, g_m \rangle$ as $n,m \to \infty$ exists. Can someone give me a hint?  What bugs me is that $f_n$ converges but $g_m$ doesn't necessarily converge. Let's say $f_n$ and $g_m$ converge. Then I would get the following:
$$
\langle f_n – f + f, g_m – g + g \rangle = \langle f_n – f, g_m – g \rangle + \langle f_n – f, g \rangle + \langle f, g_m – g \rangle + \langle f, g \rangle,
$$
Which converges to $\langle f, g \rangle$ as $n, m \to \infty$.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Could you clarify the statement of the question: What does converges 'exactly' mean? And what conditions exist on the sequence $(g_m)$?

Comment: Just edited my post again

Answer (score 1):

Since $\|f_n - f\| \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, we know $f_n \to f$ in $L^2[0,1]$, and hence $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence:
$$
\|f_n - f_m\| \to 0
$$
as $n,m \to \infty$, speaking loosely. More precisely, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there's an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n, m \geq N$ implies
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon &\geq \|f_n - f_m\| && \mbox{Def'n of Cauchy seq.} \\
&= \| f_n - g_m + g_m - f_m \| \\
&= \|(f_n - g_m) - (f_m - g_m) \| \\
&\geq \bigg| \| f_n - g_m \| - \| f_m - g_m \| \bigg| && \mbox{Reverse triangle inequal.} \\
\end{align*}

Of course, as soon as we stuck $g_m$ inside the norm, we made some assumptions about it, at least $g_m \in L^2[0,1]$ (related to assumptions made by your statement about $\langle f_n, g_m \rangle$). Does this help?

Comment: Sry, may be a little late but I haven´t really looked at this thread for quite some time. Could you elaborate why $\; <f_n;g_m>\;$converges ?